# UITableViewCell's textfield endediting not calling

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

UITableViewCell's UITextField's textFieldDidEndEditing not calling

```
 cell.txtExpenseTitle.delegate = self
    cell.txtExpensePrice.delegate = self
```

Comment: Can you please upload the whole code?

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

First, check delegate and then this method calling properly

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
   if textField == txtExpenseTitle {  

    }
   if textField == txtExpensePrice { 

    }
}
```